# How do I end an org capture template with whitespace?

Tags: org-mode, whitespace, org-capture

I want to make an org capture template that ends in whitespace. Specifically, I want to make TODOs that are scheduled. From `emacs -Q`, I'm starting with this template:

```
(cl-pushnew '("T" "TODO scheduled later" entry (file "~/org/todo.org")
              "* TODO %?\nSCHEDULED: ")
            org-capture-templates :test #'equal)
```

But this template ends up with this text (I'll add pipe characters at the end of the line to indicate my issue):

```
* TODO |
SCHEDULED:|
```

I want there to be a space as the last character of the template, so the TODOs can be formatted the same way the function `#'org-todo` formats lines. How can I make this happen?

Comment: This doesn't add whitespace, but it does make the `SCHEDULED` line more powerful: use `SCHEDULED: %^t` to pop up the mini agenda  when capturing. This should also take care of formatting.

Comment: @EFLS yes, that does handle it pretty well. I also changed the template to prompt for the TODO headline first (with `%^{todo text}`), so I don't select a day until after I've written it -- this is the order that makes more sense for me. Thanks for suggesting that.